# Shockwave flash for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: flash

I had shockwave flash installed on Ubuntu 15.10 with Firefox. 
Now I have updated to 16.04, it appears to no longer be available. Or at least I can't find it in the usual ways. I understand it is no longer updated, but where can I get the last version available?
Where is it to be found? Or should I re-install Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: Have you tried downloading it from the Adobe website? They have an APT package for Ubuntu.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Those are different topics. _Shockwave flash_ refers to the plugin, and an updated overview of Flash on Ubuntu is available on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html).

Answer (score 4):

Info

> Q: [The difference between the Adobe Shockwave and Flash Players?](https://helpx.adobe.com/shockwave/kb/shockwave-player-faq.html)
>
> A: Shockwave Player displays content created with Adobe Director 11.5
>   software such as high-performance multiuser games, interactive 3D
>   product simulations, online entertainment, and training applications.
>   By using extensions, developers can extend the capabilities of
>   Shockwave Player to play back custom-built applications.
>
> Flash Player displays content created with Flash Professional CS5.
>   This content includes web applications, website user interfaces,
>   interactive online advertising, and rich Internet applications (RIAs)
>   created using Flex.

Do you really need Shockwave or only Flash plugin?

the flash plugins is available for 16.04 [Install Flash Player for Watching Video in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus (LTS)](http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2016/03/install-flash-player-for-watching-video.html)

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Adobe Shockwave Player is not available anymore for Linux. **It's obsolete**. It doesn't work with modern browsers and operating systems.

[image]

The even list PowerPC based Macs. In 2006 Apple switched to Intel.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I don' t know what I actually needed. The only message I got was "you need a plug-in to view this site".  No indication whatsoever as to which plugin is needed. I don't care whether it's fashionable or not, I just need to be able to view the site. Then comparing with a firefox that works on another computer, the only additional plugin i could see was shockwave flash.

Answer (score 2):

Start by doing:   **sudo apt purge --remove adobe-flashplugin flashplugin-installer pepperflashplugin-nonfree** (to remove older versions of flashplugin and pepperflashplugin.

Then do:  **sudo apt install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash** .
If you get any message of a missing file or any error message, go to http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/adobe-flashplugin , select "adobe-flashplugin" 32 or 64-bit deb package and select to open it with "software install(default)". Softaware center will open on adobe-flashplugin page. Press install, then restart your browser and you are done.  I hope it helps !